# Angular translation not working in OwlCarousel 2 directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-translate, owl-carousel-2

I have a slider, using OwlCarousel 2 in a directive. On the carousel, each item's content will be controlled by translate filter.

But, when I drag the carousel, the content will not be translated. Instead, they show the initial Angular markup.

Could anyone please help me to fix this? Or give me any ways to workaround? If you need any update or more information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

sliderDirective.$inject = [];
function sliderDirective() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'A',
    'scope': {},
    'link': function(scope, element) {
      var owl = $(element).owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: true
      });
    }
  };
}
app.directive('slider', sliderDirective);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'TITLE': 'Hello',
    'FOO': 'This is a paragraph'
  });
 
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    'TITLE': 'Hallo',
    'FOO': 'Dies ist ein Absatz'
  });
 
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

```css
li {
  width:60%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.15.2/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">

 <ul slider class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <li class="item">{{'TITLE' | translate}}</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```